# How to close webview all together in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a website in React JS.The website will work like a webview as it will be attached to android/IOS application.
In the website i have a cross button.
On that button press i want to trigger native bridge event which will close whole webview all together.
Let me know how can i achieve same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mhmm, android and iOS are creating a special object on `window` when loading a website in a webview.. in Android it is called `window.android`, in iOS it's `window.webkit` and a special userAgent agent which matches like

```js
navigator.userAgent.match("CriOS") === null // detects chrome on iOS
```

In Android, it is possible to create "callbacks" on this `android` object which can be called from the websites ReactJS code like:

```js
window.android?.share(content)
```

In iOS, you can go with `messageHandlers` and it will look something like this:

```js
window.webkit?.messageHandlers?.showSharing?.postMessage(url)
```

I cannot show you the native App code for these two examples as i'm the Frontend-Developer in our company and not the App-Developer ^^

But, i would assume that's the way to achieve this. You need a way to call a method directly in your native app code to have the ability to actually close the webview - the website itself cannot achieve this.